# Variable access within object scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I access the values of "runit" and "property2"?

```
$("#selector").draggable({
    property1: "myvalue",
    property2: "myvalue",
    property3: "myvalue",
    start: function() {
        var runit = 'one value';
    },
    stop: function(){                       
        //Access Value of runit
        //Acess Value of property2
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access `runit` from `stop()` as it is scoped only to the `start()` method. You *should* be able to access `property2` with

```
this.property2
```

You *could* add `runit` to the object's properties, eg

```
{
    property1: "myvalue",
    property2: "myvalue",
    property3: "myvalue",
    runit:     null,
    start: function() {
        this.runit = 'one value';
    },
    stop: function(){
        console.log(this.runit);
        console.log(this.property2);
    }
}
```

A possibly working example - http://jsfiddle.net/9rZJH/

Comment: you can access runit if you declare it without `var`. Then it would be global.

Comment: @bhamlin Cheers, I've clarified my answer

Comment: While you **should** be able to access the object’s scope inside the start and stop methods, it is not a safe assumption. It depends on how they are called internally.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate; the thisBinding is (almost) purely dependant on how the method is called, and your solution certainly doesn't guarantee the appropriate binding in the general case, nor in the specific case of jQueryUI's draggable event handlers.

Comment: @phil f.ex `obj.stop.call(window)` will set `this` as window scope and `this.runit` will be undefined.

Comment: @David Ah, fair enough. I hadn't considered `call()`

Comment: @Phil, your example fails in cases more fundamental than just using `call`; in particular any out of context reference to the function.

Comment: And jQuery have a nasty habit of calling callbacks with the chained HTML element as thisBinding...

Comment: @davin Care to elaborate? Could you modify / update the JSFiddle, I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: I find that particular jQuery habit rather helpful, and not nasty at all. In any case, I would be glad to elaborate: `var obj = {foo:42, bar:function(){ alert(this.foo); }}, fn = obj.bar; fn();` You should be expecting an alert of `42`, notice that that fails and I haven't used `.call()`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access `runit` you need to define it outside the object’s scope:

```
var runit;

$("#selector").draggable({
    property1: "myvalue",
    property2: "myvalue",
    property3: "myvalue",
    start: function() {
        runit = 'one value';
    },
    stop: function(){                       
        //Access Value of runit
        console.log(runit);
        //Acess Value of property2
        console.log(this.property2);
    }
});
```

`property2` *should* be accessible via `this.property2` but that depends on how the stop method is called internally.

Comment: Did you mean "object's scope" because there's no such thing (in js) as object scope.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just return `runit`. I mean, it all depends on what you want to accomplish:

```
start: function() {
    var runit = 'one value';
    // Stuff
    return { runit: runit };
},
method: function(){
    var foo = this.start().runit;
}
```